# How to get input value with no id using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have an editable DataTabe and when edit mode, the generated html is exactly as shown below:

```
<td><form><input autocomplete="off" name="value" ></form></td>
```

There is s TextBox as input and I need t get the value of this input. However, I cannot give id as there is no configuration of DataTable and I decided to get the value using Javaascipt. I have tried many different methods like **closest()** as shown below, but cannot get the value. Is it possible to grab it?

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); 
$tds = $row.find("td");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `document.querySelector`:

```
var input = document.querySelector('[name="value"]`);
```

Or, using jQuery, you could also use the same selector:

```
var input = $('[name="value"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using jQuery; you can target the name attribute directly and to get a value of the input use .val(), like so:

```
$("input[name='value']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentInput=null;

$("input").focus(function(e)
{
   currentInput=e.target or this;//here you can get currently editing textfeild or may be $(this) if this is wrong
});
```

then you can get `currentInput.value()`